# Manage Excel-Access-linked-tables from Excel (push update)

Tags: excel, ms-access, linked-tables, vba

The relational data is stored in tables in Excel. Access serves as "BI-Layer" querying the linked Excel tables. The analysis is done with pivots in the same Excel that holds the stored tables using Excel queries as source, resulting in a "roundtrip" Excel->Access->Excel.

I hoped that clicking refresh on the Connections in Excel would also provide an option to trigger Access to refresh the linked tables ("transitive refresh"), but in the end I always have to open Access to trigger the refresh.

Handling the linked-tables from Excel would allow to trigger the refresh and would also enable multiple users to share the BI logic. So the link is not stored in Access with a local path but in Excel with a remote path to Access.

Does a built-in functionality exist in Office 2013?

If not, any other suggestions besides:

1) VBA and SELECT * INTO? Which means that table structured additionally needs to be maintained in Access but providing more type security

2) using VBA TransferSpreadsheet acLink instead of acImport, maybe there even exist a TransferTable-Method but constantly creating new links seems even more wrong than using approach 1.

3) The third option is to update the linked tables in access with vba from excel (prefered solution).

```
Public Sub UpdateLinkedTables()
  Dim accApp As Access.Application
  Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  Call accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(Config.msaDbPath)
  Call IterateLinkedTables(accApp)
  Call accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
  Call accApp.Quit
  Set accApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub IterateLinkedTables(accApp As Access.Application)
    Dim tdf As TableDef
   'Debug.Print accApp.CurrentDb.TableDefs.Count
    For Each tdf In accApp.CurrentDb.TableDefs
     If Left(tdf.Connect, 10) = "Excel 12.0" Then
        'Debug.Print tdf.Name & "  " & tdf.Connect
        tdf.RefreshLink
     End If
    Next tdf
'Set tdf = db.TableDefs
End Sub
```

I am able to run the above code on the first time without any errors. But second time and ongoing I receive a Run-time error '3027': Cannot update. Database or objects is read-only.
The tables seem to get updated anyhow but nevertheless I would like to fix the error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry apparently the roundtrip works as designed.
When I hit refresh all in Excel the related access queries are refreshed including the access linked-excel-table, no need to execute the posted vba script.
I handled a lot of data and apparently had error values in single rows maybe that caused the not transitive updated in the first place.

All the best